# Limit of time to get an output on MAGMA

Tags: magma-cas

I would to ask you if there is a way to put a MAGMA command that stop a function in a script if the occurring time is greater than a certain prefixed time $T\geq 0$ (for example $T=15 $ minutes ). After this stop, I would that the script
goes on to compute.

I looked at the website [MAGMA](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) but it seems there isn’t anything that could do this.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1.** Magma's `Alarm(s)` function (described [here](https://conf.math.illinois.edu/Software/magma/text106.html)).
This will quit Magma after `s` seconds. So, if you are fine with closing Magma completely, you could insert `Alarm(15 * 60);` at the appropriate location.

**Option 2.** For whatever reason, you may not want to completely quit Magma and maybe move on to the next lines. This seems equivalent to wanting to cancel a command midway, i.e., pressing Ctrl-C. However, note that this may not immediately terminate the command, as Magma tries to tries to interrupt at a "convenient point" ([source](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/5)).

Here is one outline how you can simulate the Ctrl-C, using Sage: Note that Sage has a Magma interface (more details [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/magma.html)).

Sage also has an "alarm" function that can time certain processes. (Maybe you can Google this and find a more canonical reference, but [here is what I have](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/50331/can-one-now-set-a-timelimit-on-operation-in-sagemath/).)

An example of how you could now use it is as follows:
Suppose your Magma code is

```
A := 1;
DoSomethingDifficult(A);
DoEasyThings(A);
```

You would convert it to the following Sage code:

```
magma.eval("A := 1;")
alarm(15 * 60)
try:
    magma.eval("DoSomethingDifficult(A);")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Did not work! :(")
cancel_alarm()
magma.eval("DoEasyThings(A);")
```

Note: This seems like a quite hack-y workaround, and I don't know the internal workings well enough to assure that "nothing weird will go wrong".